# Magento 1.9 Custom Module Error

Tags: magento-1.9, module, custom

I am a noob of Magento 1.9.

I have these custom module files:

```
app/code/local/mypackage/custommodule/block/mymodulename.php
app/code/local/mypackage/custommodule/etc/config.xml
app/code/local/mypackage/custommodule/templates/mymodulename.phtml
app/code/local/mypackage/custommodule/templates/mymodulename_1.phtml
app/code/local/mypackage/custommodule/templates/mymodulename_2.phtml
```

I've added some code to block/mymodulename.php and then I want to use that module in the homepage with the template called mymodulename_2.phtml.

mymodulename_1 is already working correctly elsewhere in my site but I don't know how (cause I'm noob).

This is the config.xml of the module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mypackage_Custommodule>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Mypackage_Custommodule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <mypackagecustommodule>
                <class>Mypackage_Custommodule_Block</class>
            </mypackagecustommodule>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

I've tried to put the module in the homepage with

```
app/design/frontend/mytheme/mypackage/layout/local.xml

<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
       <block type="mypackagecustommodule/mymodulename" name="mypackage_custommodule_mymodulename_2" template="mypackagecustommodule/mymodulename_2.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

> The result is this and I don't know why it can't find the file:
>
> File not found in
> /home/mypackage/mypackagemagento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php
>
> 0 /home/mypackage/mypackagemagento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241):
> mageCoreErrorHandler()
>
> 1 /home/mypackage/mypackagemagento/app/code/local/Mypackage/Custommodule/Block/mymodulename.php(29):
> Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView()

Thank you in advice.

Answer (score 0):

all file is like

```
app/code/local/Mypackage/Custommodule/Block/Mymodulename.php
app/code/local/Mypackage/Custommodule/etc/config.xml
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/mypackagecustommodule/mymodulename.phtml
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/mypackagecustommodule/mymodulename_1.phtml
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/mypackagecustommodule/mymodulename_2.phtml
```

config.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mypackage_Custommodule>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Mypackage_Custommodule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <mypackagecustommodule>
                <class>Mypackage_Custommodule_Block</class>
            </mypackagecustommodule>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Mymodulename.php file code is like

```
class Mypackage_Custommodule_Block_Mymodulename extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

}
```

local.xml code

```
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="mypackagecustommodule/mymodulename" name="mypackage_custommodule_mymodulename_2" template="mypackagecustommodule/mymodulename_2.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```